# Search Subfolders for File Then Copy

Tags: function, vbscript, scripting, subdirectory

I am attempting to search a directory's subfolders for a specific filename, then copy that file to a target folder. Please disregard all `WScript.Echo` statements. The script passes through the FileExists if statement but continues to fail the copy process. Here's the loop where I think it's going wrong.

```
Option Explicit

' The list of files to copy. Should be a text file with one file on each row. No paths - just file name.
Const strFileList = "C:\Users\206565068\Desktop\hardDriveScript\filelist.txt"

' Should files be overwriten if they already exist? TRUE or FALSE.
Const blnOverwrite = FALSE

' The source path for the copy operation.
Const strRootFolder = "C:\Users\206565068\Desktop\sourceTest"

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objFolder, objFolderItem, objSubFolders, subfolder
Dim strFullPathToSearch
strFullPathToSearch = ""

Const ForReading = 1
Dim objFileList
Set objFileList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileList, ForReading, False)

Dim strSourceFilePath
strSourceFilePath = ""

Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Public Function FindAndCopy()
    ' Get the target path for the copy operation.
    Dim strTargetFolder
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select target folder", 0 )
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then WScript.Quit
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    strTargetFolder = objFolderItem.Path

    FindAndCopy = ""
    WScript.Echo "Step one"
    WScript.Echo strRootFolder

    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until objFileList.AtEndOfStream
        ' Read next line from file list and build filepaths
        strFileToCopy = objFileList.Readline
        WScript.Echo strFileToCopy
        WScript.Echo "Step Two"
        Set objSubFolders = FSO.GetFolder(strRootFolder).SubFolders
        For Each subfolder In objSubFolders
            WScript.Echo "Searching subs"
            WScript.Echo subfolder.Path
            strFullPathToSearch = strRootFolder & "\" & subfolder.Name & "\" & strFileToCopy
            strSourceFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFullPathToSearch, strFileToCopy)
            strTargetFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(strTargetFolder, strFileToCopy)
            If FSO.FileExists(strFullPathToSearch) Then
                ' Copy file to specified target folder.
                WScript.Echo "File Exists"
                Err.Clear
                objFSO.CopyFile strSourceFilePath, strTargetFilePath, blnOverwrite
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    ' File copied successfully
                    iSuccess = iSuccess + 1
                    If InStr(1, WScript.Fullname, "cscript.exe", 1) > 0 Then
                        ' Running cscript, output text to screen
                        WScript.Echo strFileToCopy & " copied successfully"
                    End If
                Else
                    ' Error copying file
                    iFailure = iFailure + 1
                    WScript.Echo "File failed"
                    TextOut "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") trying to copy " & strFileToCopy
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Loop

    strResults = strResults & vbCrLf
    strResults = strResults & iSuccess & " files copied successfully." & vbCrLf
    strResults = strResults & iFailure & " files generated errors" & vbCrLf
    WScript.Echo strResults
End Function
```

Comment: Do you receive an error when it tries to copy the files?

Comment: How *exactly* does the code "continue to fail the copy process"?

Comment: I should specify further that I'm reading a list of file names from a txt file. 

The script never actually copies anything. It appears to be unable to find the file within the subfolder. It loops through each filename but does nothing.. 

I know the code is rough but it's my first script. i appreciate the help

Comment: No error is received, just nothing copies

Comment: Just to make sure: is what you posted your actual (complete) code, or did you strip it down for your question? Because the code you posted never invokes `FindAndCopy`.